# Is it possibile to overwrite SharedPreference in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to overwrite my whole SharedPreference data. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
    SharedPreferences settings = context
            .getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

And do later on I would like to do...

```
    context.setSharedPreference(settings);
// Or something like this
```

I am having a hard time figuring out and finding how to rewrite the whole sharedPreference. Any ideas? Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3687333/2649012. Note that `apply()` is faster than `commit()`.

Comment: follow this link and you can overwrite by again call the function createLoginSession()

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29252749/4693713

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/24609522/1164529